# javascript function not calling from code behind when i'm calling another function within same click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'M calling a javascript function from code behind its working fine but when I'M calling another function from same code behind its not working,

code mentioned below.

```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "script", "copy1('" + Macid + "','" + JobName.Text + "','" + Process.Text + "','" + Issue.Text + "') ", true);

    //test(index1);
```

javascript function copy1 is not working when I'M calling Test(int index); within same button click.

is there any another way to call both function from same click event?

Comment: is Test(index) also javascript function or server side function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by my self .

under text function one more javascript function is calling so i removed that call from text function now its working.